# Input buttons on Chrome mobile are showing up weird

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm testing a site I built and when I go into Chrome mobile, the button styles are showing up very randomly and not according to the CSS. The "No" button is what it's *supposed* to look like, but the "Yes" button isn't receiving the styles for some reason. Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Here's my code for the buttons:

`<input {yesCoregOnclick} type="button" name="{yesCoreg}" value="yes" class="coreg-yes" id="leadid_tcpa_disclosure_{coregOfferId}">Yes</input>`

`<input {noCoregOnclick} type="button" name="{yesCoreg}" value="no" class="coreg-no">No</input>`

[image]

Comment: You only included the code for the "yes" button. Could you include the code for the "no" button?

Comment: @M-Chen-3 it's the same as the Yes button

Comment: does .coreg-yes include the exact same styling as your .coreg-no in your css?

Comment: We need to see your CSS stylesheet to help you out better.